# директивы Robots.txt с закрывающим слэшем и без него

Tags: robots.txt

Подскажите, будьте добры.

Есть туча страниц на сайте с таким url
https://site.ru/region/14/18

И осталась вторая туча страниц с закрывающим слэшем в конце
https://site.ru/region/14/18/
(с них редирект стоит на url без / в конце)

Пытаюсь избавиться от возникновения дублей, указывая в robots.txt такую директиву

**Disallow:/regions/звездочка/звездочка/**

То есть я хочу запретить индексировать страницы со слешем в конце.
А аналогичные url без закрывающего слэша

**/regions/звездочка/звездочка**

оставить открытыми для индексации.

Но анализ роботс.тхт мне говорит, что эти страницы тоже запрещены в роботс.тхт

Что сделала неправильно и как исправить?
Спасибо!

Что-то в предпросмотре вижу, что * заменяется в сообщении на еще один /, поэтому словом написала - звездочка

Comment: Вам необходимо сделать редирект с кодом 301. Всё остальное будет ни к чему.

Comment: Редирект у меня уже сделан. Но несколько тысяч этих страниц "висят" в яндекс.вебмастере. Я пытаюсь их оттуда удалить, а для этого нужно их запретить в роботс.тхт   Ждать, пока Яндекс сам их удалит не могу, к сожалению, нужно ускорить процесс

Comment: Ещё раз удостоверьтесь что редирект с кодом 301. И тогда при посещении сайта роботом он их начнёт выкидывать.

Comment: То есть запретить в роботс.тхт именно такие url не получится? Там сейчас стоит Disallow:/regions/звездочка/
Disallow:/regions/звездочка/звездочка/

Comment: Запретить можно, но тогда насколько я знаю, яндекс всё равно будет учитывать эти страницы. Ему нужно увидеть, что там стоит редирект и он тогда будет знать что эти страницы больше не нужны.

Comment: Редирект был поставлен в первую очередь. Но после того, как началась активная работа в этом направлении, Яндекс нашел больше 10 000 страниц такого типа дублей. Мне действительно нужно ускорить процесс из удаления этих url из базы поисковика. Это можно быстро сделать вручную. Но требуется запретить данный тип адресов в роботс.тхт